# How to get a random float value between 0 and 100

Tags: java, random

I need a random float value between 0 and 100.

Easiest way to do this would be

```
Random generator = new Random();
float x = generator.nextFloat() * 100;
```

There's only a little Problem. nextFloat() returns values in interval [0,1), but I need values from [0,1].

Anyone an idea how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724404/random-floating-point-double-in-inclusive-range

Comment: So random numbers between 0 and 99.99999 is not close enough?  Even if you _could_, the odds of getting _exactly_ 1 are infinitesimal.

Comment: If you are doing this to get _integers_ between 0 and 100 inclusive then just multiply by 101 instead of 100.